# How to invert the result of a regular expression

Tags: regex

I have a file that contains records like these:

```
1 "The number one" 0.1 111 "one" .1 "uno" "UNO!" "#ONE"
2 "El numero dos" 2.0 222 "The number two" 2.02 "two" "TWO!" "#DOS"
```

I need to replace the spaces between numbers and strings with commas to have this file as result:

```
1,"The number one",0.1,111,"one",.1,"uno","UNO!","#ONE"
2,"El numero dos",2.0,222,"The number two",2.02,"two","TWO!","#DOS"
```

I created a regular expression that does the opposite, it gets the numbers and strings:

```
(?:\"[ !\x23-\xFF]*\"|[\d.])
```

How can I invert the result of my regular expression? Can you help me to create a regular expression that does exactly what I need?

**UPDATE 1**

The file may contain special characters in strings and the order of string and numbers(can be decimal) is variable.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Just matching spaces alone won't work here, because Kaz doesn't want to touch the spaces which are inside quoted strings, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ the following works:

**Find:**

```
("|\d)\s("|\d)
```

**Replace:**

```
$1,$2
```

Comment: What if there is a string after another string? Like: `"uno" "one"`

Comment: I updated my answer with an alternative which handles better all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?:\.|\d)(\s)\"|\"(\s)(?:\.|\d)
```

Replace group 1 and 2 with `,`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/H3dFFa/2

This regex seems to catch the spaces too:

```
[\.\d"](\s)[\.\d"]?
```

Replace only group 1

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/H3dFFa/3